# SQL Query For Multiple Indirect Relationships

Tags: sql, data-modeling, alasql

I have a question about whether I can extract indirect relationship information from a SQL database, just using SQL.

A modelling tool I'm using is based upon an SQL database that essentially has just two tables: Elements and Relations. The table definitions are as follows

```
Elements:
id, type, name

Relations:
id, type, name, source, target
```

Elements is just a list of entities with a system generated unique ID, and Relations (also with a unique Id) uses the Elements' unique IDs to define relationships between them in the 'source' and 'target' columns.

What I'm trying to figure out is: for any two elements in the model, e.g. A and D, or A and E, in the diagram below - are they linked, and if so how - including by multiple indirect relationships through other elements?

[image: Example Model]

I know I could solve this problem by writing some procedural code that recursively trawls the Relations table exhaustively checking each relationship between A and D (or E). But this is not straightforward to code.

So I wondered if anyone can point me at the best solution to this problem?
Specifically, is there an SQL-only solution to this problem or will I have to write some procedural code?

The SQL DB in question is alaSQL underpinning the [Archi](https://www.archimatetool.com/) modelling tool. But I'm also interested if other solutions, as pumping the data into a new DBMS is not a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a recursive CTE? `with recursive relation ( select 0 as distance, "left", "right" from relations union all select distance + 1, l.left, r.right from relations l join relation r on l.right=r.left and r.left != l.right) select * from relation where left = 'A' and right='E' and distance < 5` (of course, this only pushes the recursion into the DB instead of keeping it in your procedural code ...)

Comment: I agree that this would usually be solved with some recursive query, but I don't know whether alaSQL supports them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Been a very long time since I had to delve into SQL so CTEs and recursive queries new to me. But there is quite a lot in the suggested query that alaSQL doesn't support, so I'll have to hunt around for a DBMS that does. Thanks.